# Design parameters for combo organs

Tags: instruments, modulation, tremolo

What are the typical tremelo and vibrato characteristics for electric organs, like the Vox Continetial and Farfisa organs?

I'd like some ball park parameter values, i.e. modulation frequencies around `x` Hz, and vibrato widths around `y` Hz to start off my pure-data model with.

Answer (score 1):

Typical tremolo speed/rate frequency range:

**0.1 Hz - 10 Hz**

Higher frequencies will start to sound like actual tones and not tremolo pulses ([source](https://docs.cycling74.com/max5/tutorials/msp-tut/mspchapter08.html#Tremolo)).

Classic rock BPM is probably around 120-160 bpm or so (1/4). If the tremolo is supposed to roughly follow the 1/8 tempo you'll end up around **4 Hz** (but you may want to go a bit lower to match a triplet 1/4 feeling).

As for the vibrato tonal range or width - you can't specify that in a general Hz range, as the range changes logarithmically. I will specify that in [cents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(music)) instead.

Most vibrato/modulation ranges I have worked with goes from:

**0.. +/- 100 cents** (or +/- one half step)

Some models go to a full step (i.e. +/- 200 cents) though. To avoid too obvious disharmony it is preferable to modulate < 100 Cents

A value of **33 cents** is probably not way off - it will make the tonal change noticeable while not causing obvious disharmonies.